# No options of ubuntu and windows 10 in grub menu when I dual booted

Tags: dual-boot

I dual booted my windows 10 pc with ubuntu (HP i5 7th gen) using usb flash drive method. It asked me to restart but when I restart the computer (with usb connected) there are no options for windows 10 or ubuntu.. It is like this,
                    GNU GRUB version 2.02
Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects

Thats all.
When I tried installing it again, it says Ubuntu 18.04 is already installed.. but I can't find it where. 
When usb is not connected and I start the computer.. windows 10 automatically opens.
Please help me with this...
P.S: I turned off secure boot in UEFI settings

Answer (score 0):

Remove the USB drive and boot, then see if Windows and Ubuntu show in the menu

Answer (score -2):

In BIOS - settings you should disable UEFI and enable LEGACY - it could be that this helps. For BIOS - settings you need to press key 'F2' when booting your machine. Check too in BIOS - settings how USB-ports are supported and if they are enabled.

Comment: But legacy is for os lower than windows 8 right? Moreover it says changing into legacy may lead to a situation in which current os cant boot

Comment: No - not right - and who downvoted me without re-thinking ... ??? Many have no clue, and then downvote me, is this okay ?!